# $(document).ready() doesn't run after f:ajax rendering

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf-2

I have some `jQuery` code that runs on every `$(document).ready()` event.
I also have some `<f:ajax>` tags that do re-rendering of some parts of the page.

I noticed that when I rerender a component, the `$(document).ready()` doesn't get called.

Is there a way to run javascript code after every `<f:ajax>` rerendering?
(I can technically use the `onevent` tag but that's the unfavourable solution to me since I will have to call the function on every `<f:ajax>`)

*Just for illustration, this is the jQuery Code:*

```
$(document).ready(function() { ...CODE... }
```

*And the JSF code:*

```
<f:ajax event="click" render=":someComponentID"/>
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE** This question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719336/jsf2-execute-javascript-after-every-postback). I'm looking into it.

**UPDATE2**
This is easily solvable using the JSF Javascript event binding:

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data){
  if (data.status === 'success') {
    // Do stuff here
  }
}
```

Read more about it under the JSF 2 reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$(document).ready()` event fires once, when the DOM has fully loaded from the initial load.

An ajax event may change the DOM, but it doesn't reload the page, so the `$(document).ready()` won't fire again.

I noticed the way Google solved this problem in Gmail is by using [a high frequency timer](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/07/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-using.html).

Comment: Interesting Article! This might be the answer. I'll wait and see if there are more ideas.

Comment: on second thought, a Timer may not work here. I need to know when the event took place.

Answer (score 0):

Use events and listeners..

Have a read at [Ajax tag events and listeners](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/09/26/ajax-tag-events-and-listeners)

Comment: As I said in the question "I can technically use the onevent tag but that's the unfavourable solution to me since I will have to call the function on every <f:ajax>".

Comment: The post i linked to does not use the `onevent` attribute but the `listener` attribute. In anyway, jsf provide a callback model (event/listeners).. don't know why you do not want to use it.. You ***want*** to call the function on every `f:ajax` .. right ?

Comment: would using a `h:outputScript` and targeting with the `render` attribute of the `ajax` call work ? (*and in that script do what you want..*)