# how to fix Sortable didnt work after update table?

Tags: jquery, jsf

i have a table that i update but when i update it with

```
<p:commandButton id="someId" update="table" value="Button" action="#{gestionduplanning.exec2}" />
```

but my jquery sortable code didnt work after the update .

```
 $( init );    
function init() {

            $(".list-items").sortable({
            connectWith: '.list-items',
            items: "li:not(.item.new)",
            placeholder: 'place-holder',
            scroll: false,
            tolerance: "pointer",update: function (event, ui) {
            //alert($(this));
            }, 
                receive : function(e, ui) { 

                }

        }).disableSelection();

        }
```

how to fixe the sortable after the update ??

Comment: how we can refresh jquery again ??

Comment: The answer is here by balusc http://stackoverflow.com/a/5719872/2405945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `oncomplete="init();"` to your button,

Like this:

```
<p:commandButton oncomplete="init();" id="someId" update="table" value="Button" action="#{gestionduplanning.exec2}" />
```