# Executing javascript after bean action

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using **JSF 2.0.** Is there anyway to call a javascript function after a bean method? Something like

```
<h:commandLink oncomplete="pop()" action="#{bean.method}"/>
```

I tried oncomplete, but doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719336/jsf2-execute-javascript-after-every-postback) can help you... Or if you have a small function you could write the full code in `oncomplete` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a way.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.method}">
  <f:ajax onevent="pop"/>
</h:commandLink>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function pop(data){
        if(data.status == "success"){
           ....
        }
    }
</script>
```

There are probably better ways, so if you have a better solution, feel free to leave your answer!