# Meta refresh on session.maxInactiveInterval and AJAX don't get along

Tags: ajax, jsf, redirect, session-timeout

I have JSF web page using PrimeFaces 5.1 and I want to redirect redirect to some xhtml page once session is expired.

I have set session timeout to 1 minute (for testing it will be set to 30 after that) in web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

And i have added

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval};url=#{request.contextPath}/season_expired.xhtml"/>
```

to `<h:head>` of the default template which is used on every page of the application.

Everything works fine for the most of the time (when I move between pages etc..) except when I'm using using some form where every refresh is made by AJAX. Then i get redirected after one minute.

Is there a way to "refresh" session with AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JS [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) for that which you can clear out with [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) when an ajax request is made. You can use [`jsf.ajax.addOnEvent()`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/jsdocs/symbols/jsf.ajax.html#.addOnEvent) to register a global ajax event listener function.

```
<script>
    var redirectToExpired = function() { window.location='#{request.contextPath}/expired.xhtml' };
    var expireTimeMillis = 5000;
    
    window.redirectOnExpire = setTimeout(redirectToExpired, expireTimeMillis);
    jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'begin') {
            clearTimeout(window.redirectOnExpire);
            window.redirectOnExpire = setTimeout(redirectToExpired, expireTimeMillis);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Like as with the meta refresh header, this is a bit naive as it doesn't work nicely when you have the same webapp open in multiple browser tabs. In a "forgotten" tab, the redirect will still happen in the background while you're active on the same webapp in another tab.

Better is to just not do that all, but rely on `ViewExpiredException` during a real user action. You can find in [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969) how to register an error page for that and also how the meta refresh header could be used there.

#### See also:

- [Execute JavaScript after every JSF ajax postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719336/jsf2-execute-javascript-after-every-postback/)