# Using NavigationHandler.handleNavigation doesn't show the top of the page

Tags: ajax, jsf, navigation

I am using NavigationHandler.handleNavigation as suggested here ([ExternalContext.dispatch() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163457/externalcontext-dispatch-not-working)) since I am using an ajax request.

It works but I see the next page in the middle of the page (more or less) instead of seeing it in the top of the page.

I tried using an anchor as suggested here (http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001475.htm) but it also doesn't work.

Any idea of what is happening?

Here is my code:

```
context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, null, "/user-registration.xhtml#top");
```

I have added the following in the beginning of the body of the next page:

```
<a name="top"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach to scroll the window to top is [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) with `x` and `y` of `0`:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

This keeps your URL free of hash fragment clutter.

In order to invoke it on success of every JSF ajax event, include the following script in the document.

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
    if (data.status == "success") {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

#### See also:

- [Execute JavaScript after every JSF ajax postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719336/execute-javascript-after-every-jsf-ajax-postback/)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it with the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    location.hash = "#top";
  });
</script>
```